Unity button text not displayed
I have a problem with my unity project, when I insert a UI Canva and a button with text, the text not showed up,
I tried to increase the font size, the opacity, change the text color, every possible solution, any suggestion ?
Button Components
Text Components
Canva Components

this not unity hub... and there is insufficient shown, order counts, colour counts - we dont know if this is white on white.. probably its behind the block.. who knows.

how do you know that this is not unity hub, can you explain more what could be the reason of this problem .

Because Ive been using unity for a LONG time and thats the unity IDE, hub is well a list of projects and how to install  the unity IDE.. so no, this is not hub...  Hub is more of a launcher....

okay got it now, tell the me what informations should i provide so you can help me in this

well you could start with working through what i listed..

We need screenshots of the components for each object that are in hierarchy of Canvas, with the Canvas components as well.

I did what you asked in the answer below

I am sorry you will find it in the question above not the answer

Your font size is 300. This is extremely large, and your buttons are extremely small. Try setting the font size to something smaller, like 10 or 1 to test.


It's better to check the resault in Scene window, and not in Game or in Simulator.

Probably you didn't setup TMPro properly. Because on your screenshot TMP comonent doesn't have any font set in FontAsset property. When you add any game object with TMP component to the scene at first time, the TMP Import windows will appear. And you'll should press button Import TMP Essentials.


Use Auto Size property to setup text, that just has been added. Set min size to 0 or any small number, and max size to big number as on screenshot. It will help you to avoid situation of incorrect font size.



